# Doctrine does not create table with schema or database prefix neither with `schema` attribute

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I want to separate some tables to different database or schema. When I just use the annotation `@ORM\Table(name="mytable")`, the command `doctrine:schema:update` generate the table in the database. But using the annotation `@ORM\Table(name="mydb.mytable")` or `@ORM\Table(name="mytable", schema="mydb")` the command `doctrine:schema:update` does not generate the table in the database. I even create the database `mydb` manually on the server. I'm using `mariadb-10.3.14`.

Comment: I think you can't create a different schema with mariadb. CREATE DATABASE creates a database with the given name. To use this statement, you need the CREATE privilege for the database. CREATE SCHEMA is a synonym for CREATE DATABASE. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-database/

Comment: Sort of what @AndreaManzi has said.  While Doctrine itself will accept a schema prefix it basically does not do anything with it.  One of those annoying limitations.

Comment: @AndreaManzi I already have create database priviledge. Otherwise Doctrine wouldn't be able to create the main database using `doctrine:database:creat` then create the tables inside it.

Comment: @Cerad So prefixing the table name or using the schema attribute does not work with Doctrine on MariaDB or Mysql?

Comment: Basically.  You can actually add the schema to the table name and querys will work with an existing database.  But none of the doctrine:database or doctrine:schema commands will.  Bottom line is that you should avoid relations across schemas with the Doctrine ORM even though mysql supports them as long as they are on the same server.  Kinda sucks for some apps.

Comment: @Cerad It does not work for me. I already created the database `mydb` on the server. But Doctrine does not create the table `@ORM\Table(name="mydb.mytable")` neither `@ORM\Table(name="mytable", schema="mydb")`. It just ignore it and `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` does not output the code `create table mytable or mydb.mytable...`. It just create the table when it is like that `@ORM\Table(name="mytable")`.

Comment: Like I said, doctrine:database and doctrine:schema command will not work.  If you already have the tables created and loaded then you can query across schemas.  But the bottom line is: don't use schema.table for table names with Doctrine.

Comment: Well, That sucks. Tank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: create multiple orm-configurations like [explaned here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) in doctrine.yaml. Then place your entities in the right folder, in this example it would be src/Entity/Main or src/Entity/Customer

Comment: I have already done that. But I need foreign key between the databases. Doctrine just delete the foreign key between different entity managers. The only way they told me to do that is by prefix the table name by a schema but Doctrine just ignore the table with the schema prefix.